# instagram API ハッシュタグ

Tags: instagram

instagram API で、
希望の「ハッシュタグ」の画像を集めて、サイトに貼りたいと思っています。

サンプルとなるPHPをググりましたが、
見つかりません。

アクセストーンとか、Client IDを取得するまではできています。
あとはプログラム...

だれか、実際のプログラムでも、サイトでも、
いい感じのがあれば教えていただけると助かります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コード的には、シンプルに以下を取得するだけです。
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/[hashtag]/media/recent?access_token=[token]

しかしおそらくこれでは動かない、という状況ですよね？

実は、昨年12月のInstagramの仕様変更により、新規作成されたプロジェクトはすべて最初はSANDBOXモードで動作するようになりました。
SANDBOXモードでは、あらかじめ登録したテストユーザー（最大10人）以外の投稿を取得することができません。
またSANDBOXモード実行中は、ハッシュタグ検索で取得できる投稿件数にも上限があります。

SANDBOXモードを解除して、テストユーザー以外の投稿を取得できるようにするためには、審査を通過させる必要があります。
審査はなかなかルールが厳しく、また現在日本語に翻訳されている情報は微妙に誤りがあるので、英語ですがInstagram公式のルールを一読されるのが確実かと思います。
（基本的に期間限定のキャンペーンや自分の個人サイトにウィジェット的に載せるというのは審査通らないようです）

Comment: そうだったんですね。ご丁寧にわかりやすくありがとうございます。

色々なソースは見つかって、設置〜試して見たんですが、
どれもうまく行かない・・には、こういう理由があったんですね。

自分のやり方が悪いものばかりと思ってましたので、
これをお聞きして諦めがつきました。(-_-;)

ありがとうございました。